# Trying to create a Data Model

Tags: sql-server, database-design

It may sound stupid but it's my first experience ever with databases.

It's a simple database for a car accessories store. I was hoping when making a sale on a certain item it effects the quantity of this item, not sure if this is possible with this design. Also as shown in the image an item could be for one car or more so I thought it should be many to many.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Is this an actual project for a real business, or is it just something you're playing around with?

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment.

Comment: It's not an actual project or a homework assignment, i work at car accessories field and recently started learning C# so i thought i could make something related to my work, i couldn't think of any other project to work on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to read a business data modeling book such as those by Silverston, Hay, or Fowler
2. You are confusing a Product, which is the *specification* of an Asset (such as a vehicle). A product does not have a quantity. For cars, the Product has a model number (Mazda 3) and the Asset has the serial number (VIN xxx).
3. You should also read up on Table Inheritance (Fowler).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help i will start reading, But you know what i mean by Products is just a way to keep track of items i got and quantity, price, etc. It's more like inventory management.

Comment: Yup, I know what you mean. There are three kinds of inventory though. Those without serial numbers that are tracked only by quantity, those without serial numbers that are tracked by weight or volume, and those with serial numbers whose quantity is always 1.